# Prove that a Balanced Incomplete Block Design with parameters $(n^2, n^2+n, n+1, n, 1)$ is a finite Affine Plane

Tags: affine-geometry, combinatorial-designs

I know I need to show that those parameters imply that the following axioms hold when we consider treatments to be points and blocks to be lines:

- A1: given any two points, there is one and only one line that contains them both;
- A2: there is a set of four points, no three of which belong to one common line;
- A3: given any point $p$ and given any line $q$ that does not contain $p$, there is exactly one line that contains $p$ and contains no point of $q$.

Now, $\lambda=1$ implies that given any pair of elements, there is only one block that contains them; i.e. we get A1. I think I have some ideas about how to show A2, but I'm really stumped on how to show that A3 must hold.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p$ be a point off the line $q$. The line $q$ has points $a_1,\ldots,a_n$. There are unique lines $l_1,\ldots,l_n$ where
$l_j$ passes through $p$ and $a_j$. These lines meet only at $a$.
But there are $n+1$ lines through $p$; the last of them does not meet $q$.

Comment: Great thanks! But should it read "These lines meet only at $q$." Instead of at $a$? Also, it seems that my ideas for showing A2 aren't working out. Would you be able to point me in the right direction for that one?

Comment: For A2, since we are assuming $n\ge2$, there are at least four points.  Pick two of them, which, of course, determine a unique line $L$.  Since $n^2>n$, there is a point not on $L$.  Can you finish from here?  Since A3 has been established, you should feel free to make use of it.

Comment: Would it go something like this: By (A3), we know $\exists$ one line (say $m$) that contains $p$ and contains no point of $L$. Therefore, $m \parallel L$ $\implies$ there is another point on $m$ that is not on $L$. Hence, only two points at most are collinear $\implies$ (A2).

Comment: Everything you say seems reasonable.  If you're at all uncertain about your proof, that would be a reason to spell out the reasoning in a bit more detail.